# Automatically generated LaTeX beamer slides with R/knitr

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I am working on a LaTeX report template that automatically generates a beamer document, pulling in figures from specified directories and placing them one per slide.

Here is an example of the code that I am using for this, as a code chunk in my .Rnw document:

```
<<results='asis',echo=FALSE>>=
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library("Hmisc"))

# get the plots from the common directory
Barplots_dir<-"/home/figure/barplots"
Barplots_files<-dir(Barplots_dir)

# create a beamer slide for each plot
# use R to output LaTeX markup into the document
for(i in 1:length(Barplots_files)){
  GroupingName<-gsub("_alignment_barplot.pdf", "", Barplots_files[i]) # strip this from the filename
    file <- paste0(Barplots_dir,"/",Barplots_files[i]) # path to the figure
    cat("\\subsubsection{", latexTranslate(GroupingName), "}\n", sep="") # don't forget you need double '\\' because one gets eaten by R !!
    cat("\\begin{frame}{", latexTranslate(GroupingName), " Alignment Stats}\n", sep="") 
    cat("\\includegraphics[width=0.9\\linewidth,height=0.9\\textheight,keepaspectratio]{", file, "}\n", sep="")
    cat("\\end{frame}\n\n") 
}  
@
```

However I recently came across [this](http://yihui.name/en/2012/06/enjoyable-reproducible-research/)  article by [Yihui Xie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559676/yihui) which includes a remark about `cat("\\includegraphics{}")` being a bad idea. Is there a reason for this, and is there a better option?

To be clear, these figures are generated by other programs as part of a larger pipeline; generating them within the document is not an option, but I need the document to be able to dynamically find and insert them into the report. I know that there are some capabilities to do this directly from within LaTeX itself but `cat`'ing out the LaTeX markup I need seemed like an easier and more flexible task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cat("\\includegraphics{}")` is *likely* to be a bad idea if you are from the old Sweave world (where one might need to open a graphics device, draw a plot, close the device, and `cat("\\includegraphics{}")`). [No kittens will be killed](http://yihui.name/en/2012/06/enjoyable-reproducible-research/) as long as you understand what you are doing. Your use case seems to be very reasonable to me, and I don't have a better approach.